# How to test a API Gateway?

Tags: api, testing, automated-tests, gateway, express-gateway

I want to make tests on a API Gateway with release with 'Express-Gateway'. I see 'express-gateway-test-tools', but there are no manual or 'how to'. Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you seen the (admittedly sparse) information at https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-gateway-test-tools?